# Can i change value of final int

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and I am trying to create a game. It is a very simple Guess the number game.I want to change the value of the correct answer if he user guesses correctly. I am unsure how to do this. his is my code for on create:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button subm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView tv1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final EditText userG=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Random rand=new Random();
    final int correctAnswer=rand.nextInt(100)+1;
    subm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int userNum=Integer.parseInt(userG.getText().toString());
            if(userNum>100 || userNum<0){
                tv1.setText("Enter a number between 1 and 100");
            }
            else{
            if(userNum==correctAnswer){

                tv1.setText("YEAH! You got it right");
            }
            else if(userNum>correctAnswer){

                tv1.setText("Sorry,Your guess is too high");
            }
            else if(userNum<correctAnswer){
                tv1.setText("Sorry,Your guess is too low");
            }}
        }
    });
}
```

How do I change correctAnswer? I am forced to call it final and can't change the value.

Comment: "Can i change value of final int" - No.

Comment: declare the int value--**globally**

Comment: _"I am forced to call it final"_ how you was forced?

Comment: I fail to see why you need `correctAnswer` not to be final. You aren't trying to change it anywhere and it's local to `onCreate()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Can i change value of final int??
```

For this answer is NO..

I can understand your problem you are using it in anonymous inner class so eclipse forcefully ask you to make it final..So you want to use `correctAnswer` value within anonymous inner class so remove the `final` and define your correctAnswer globally like ..

```
private int correctAnswer;
```

then you can change value and you can access it in anonymous inner class

Comment: +1 for understanding the problem and explaining why, and how to solve it.

Comment: I tried doing that but inside the onclicklistener it says 
Cannot refer to a non-final variable correctAnswer inside an inner class defined in a different method

Answer (score 1):

final for var allocated in stack,you can never change it ,i mean the four kinds eight basic type var .
final for references(or pointers) ,you can never change the reference,but what the reference point to means , you can changed it .
for example , final List list = new ArrayList(); list is final ,it must be one ArrayList,but what in the list , you can change it .

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the value of final int because Java uses the keyword '**final**' for declaring constants & if you try to modify it then the compiler will generate error !

Or its better to not make it final !

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a container:

```
public class IntContaner {
    public int value;

    public IntContainer(int initialValue) {
        value = initialValue;
    }
}
```

And in your code, you write:

```
final IntContainer correctAnswer=new IntContainer(rand.nextInt(100)+1);
```

...which allows you to change the contents of "correctAnswer" in the OnClickListener.

Answer (score -1):

If we declare a variable as `final`  , we can't change its value.

Remove the `final` keyword , then you can change its value.

Comment: He can't remove the final if he wants to use it in the click listener