# Listview weird reaction on Clicking

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm displaying a listview with custom adapter. Each item of list view basically has a photo (Imageview) and a like (FlipImageView) button and a textView to show number of likes. I have populated the listview with 3 items. The weird issue is that when i click on the like button of second photo, there is no response (no flipping of image and no change in number of likes). Instead the first photo like button responds and the number of likes of first photo got incremented. The second weird issue is that, the first item of listview isn't populated fully (An imageview lies blank while imageview of other list items inflate fully). But when i scroll and come back to first item, it then gets inflated fully. Here is the Adapter code, xml file of each list Item, and the Listview itself. How to solve these issues?

```
class PostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<eachpost> 
{
  ArrayList<eachpost> posts;
  ViewHolder vholder;
  String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  File dir = new File (root + "/fishograph/.feed");
    public PostAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<eachpost> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.postcontent, list);
        posts = list;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos,View vu,ViewGroup vg)
    {
      final eachpost post = posts.get(pos);
      final int finalpos = pos;
      final String han = post.getHandle();
      final String imgurl = post.getDpbase64();

      if(vu == null)
      { 
        vu = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.postcontent,vg,false); 
        vholder = new ViewHolder();
        vholder.handle = ((TextView) vu.findViewById(R.id.handle));
        vholder.caption = ((TextView) vu.findViewById(R.id.caption));
        vholder.likesnum = ((TextView) vu.findViewById(R.id.likesnum));
        vholder.comnum = ((TextView) vu.findViewById(R.id.comnum));
        vholder.uploadtime = ((TextView) vu.findViewById(R.id.uploadtime));
        vholder.photo = (ImageView) vu.findViewById(R.id.imgpost);
        vholder.feeddp = (ImageView) vu.findViewById(R.id.realdp);
        vholder.like = (FlipImageView) vu.findViewById(R.id.like);
        Drawable d =getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hook_like);
        vholder.like.setFlippedDrawable(d);
        LayoutParams lp = vholder.photo.getLayoutParams();
        lp.width = width;
        lp.height = width;
        vholder.feeddp.requestLayout();
        vholder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!likes.contains(imgurl))
                   {
                    RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
                    rp.add("handle",handle);
                    rp.add("url",imgurl);
                    vholder.like.toggleFlip();
                    new AsyncHttpClient().post("Php script to increment like",rp,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int code,Throwable t,String err)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong..Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("onError like",err);
                            vholder.like.toggleFlip();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String response)
                        {
                            response = response.trim();
                            Log.d("like", response);
                            if(!response.equals("liked"))
                                { 
                                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong..Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 vholder.like.toggleFlip();
                                }
                            else
                                { likes.add(imgurl);
                                  post.incrementLikes();
                                  vholder.likesnum.setText(post.getLikes()+"");
                                }
                        }
                    });
                  }
                else
                  {
                    RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
                    rp.add("handle",handle);
                    rp.add("url", imgurl);
                    vholder.like.toggleFlip();
                    new AsyncHttpClient().post("php script url to unlike",rp,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int code,Throwable t,String err)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong..Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d("onError unlike", err);
                            vholder.like.toggleFlip();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(String response)
                        {
                            response = response.trim();
                            Log.d("unlike", response);
                            if(!response.equals("unliked"))
                                {
                                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong..Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                 vholder.like.toggleFlip();
                                }
                            else
                                { 
                                 likes.remove(imgurl);
                                 post.decrementLikes();
                                 vholder.likesnum.setText(post.getLikes()+"");
                                }
                        }
                    });
                  }
            }
        });
        vu.setTag(vholder);
      }
      else
      vholder = (ViewHolder) vu.getTag();

        vholder.handle.setText(posts.get(pos).getHandle());
        vholder.caption.setText(posts.get(pos).getCaption());
        vholder.likesnum.setText(posts.get(pos).getLikes()+"");
        vholder.comnum.setText(posts.get(pos).getComments()+"");
        vholder.uploadtime.setText(posts.get(pos).getUl());
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load("photo to load").into(vholder.photo);
        RequestParams rpdp = new RequestParams();
        Log.d("FEED POSTADAPTER load dp handle", han);
        rpdp.add("handle",han);
        new AsyncHttpClient().post("url to get DP of user", rpdp, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response)
            { 
              response = response.trim();
              Log.d("getdpurl",finalpos+response);
              if(response.contains("http"))
                  Glide.with(getActivity()).load(response).into(vholder.feeddp);
              else
                  Glide.with(getActivity()).load("url of the dp").into(vholder.feeddp);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int err,Throwable error,String response)
            {
              Log.d("Feed POSTADAPTER getdpurl", response);
            }
        });

        RequestParams rpliked = new RequestParams();
        rpliked.add("handle", handle);
        rpliked.add("url",imgurl);
        new AsyncHttpClient().post("php script to check if a photo is likes", rpliked, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response)
            { 
              response = response.trim();
              Log.d("FEED POSTADAPTER isliked", response);
              if(response.equals("islikedyes"))
              { //TODO set the hook-like
                likes.add(imgurl);
                vholder.like.setFlipped(true, false);
              }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int err,Throwable error,String response)
            {
             Log.d("Feed POSTADAPTER isliked", response);
             //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
            }
        });

            return vu;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

ListView Each Item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/dpsmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/realdp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/trans"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/framedo" />
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/handle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dpsmall"
    android:text="handle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dpsmall"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dpsmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/uploadtime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/handle"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="time"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />    
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rlimg"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/handle"
  android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
  >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgpost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
<com.sivaram.fishograph.FlipImageView
    xmlns:fiv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/like"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlimg"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/hook_unlike"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlimg"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/likesnum"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/comment" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/more"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlimg"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:src="@drawable/more" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/likesnum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/like"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/like"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/like"
    android:text="likes"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#440011" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/comnum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comment"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="comments"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#440011" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/caption"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rlimg"
    android:layout_below="@+id/like"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Caption"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The ListView Itself

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="false"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvposts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#55ea4f5f"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:animationCache="false" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, the likes of image at the previous index get incremented

Comment: Okay, i will remove the final, it was an unused variable anyways. Its always the first index :/

Answer (score 0):

I would remove all these final declarations. As you will be populating them with the value of the first item:

```
final eachpost post = posts.get(pos);
final int finalpos = pos;
final String han = post.getHandle();
final String imgurl = post.getDpbase64()
```

To:

```
eachpost post = posts.get(pos);
int finalpos = pos;
String han = post.getHandle();
String imgurl = post.getDpbase64()
```

You should see the change in `Log.d("getdpurl",finalpos+response);` When you do this. Please let me know if this doesn't solve your problem.

There is quite a bit of info on this on the web.. here's one

[Can i change value of final int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738984/can-i-change-value-of-final-int)

Comment: I did like you said. But now i'm getting errors inside new AsyncHttpClient() , saying that modifier must be changed to final.

Comment: Oh yes, i can wait. Hmm.. yeah i guess, maybe i will put the liking part as a function.

Comment: I read about the final keyword and i got what you said. I have a question, though they are final variables they have local scope right? When getView() is called everytime for each list item, It should not mess with the other items. Is that right?

Comment: Oh Good luck for the exams. I'm so stuck in this.. your help would be much appreciated. Thanks